# How to split a string without using .split()?

Tags: python

I have a function that takes a parameter string and a 'target', where the target is a substring of the string. I need to output the index of these substrings within the string. I am not allowed to use the split function, so how else would I split up the string?
Ex:
if string is "we dont need no education we dont need no thought control no we dont"
and the target was "dont"
the output would be: [1, 6, 13]

the target could also be 'we dont', so I cant split at every space.

I have this, which outputs every character in the string, although I'm not sure why it isn't outputting just 'dont' three times:

```
#
def position(string, target):
    output = []
    for target in string:
        output.append(target)
    return output

print(position('we dont need no education we dont need no thought control no we dont', 'dont'))
#
```

I thought about putting the string into a list, but that would not work because it would eliminate being able to use 'we dont' as target. So just not sure how to count the instances of the target characters as compared to the characters of the string, and then be able to output the position of the target in the string.
Edited for clarification, I hope this helps.

Also pretty sure I am not allowed to use .find()

Comment: Use a loop that calls `index()` on slices of the string.

Comment: Why is the first index `1`? `dont` is at index `3` in the string. Are you counting words instead of characters?

Comment: please add what you have tried / your research, otherwise, it might get downvoted by the community 

Comment: yes, counting words, not characters

Comment: What shall the result be for target `'nt ne'`?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, hence why this assignment is stumping me. I don't understand how to split it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this fit the requirments ?

```
example_str = "we dont need no education we dont need no thought control no we dont"
key = "dont"

count = []
word_count = 0

for i in range(len(example_str)):
     if example_str[i] == " ":
        word_count += 1

     if example_str.startswith(key, i):
        count.append(word_count)
        
print(count)
```

Gives output

```
[1, 6, 13]
```

Comment: Index in terms of words, not characters

Comment: that prints the first character of the correct target, but I need the position of the whole target, whether it be one word or more. So 'dont' would be [1, 6, 13]

Comment: Oof - I was almost done with a 30-liner using complicated list splitting and comparison when you come with a little 10-liner that only compares some strings `:´(`

Answer (score 0):

This solution works fine not only for a single word, but for any sort of substring.

##### What it returns?

List of indices of matches in terms of words

##### Code

```py
def doIt(text: str, subs: str):
    indices = []
    prev = 0
    for i in range(len(text)):
        indices.append(prev)
        if text[i] == " " and (i < len(text) - 1 and text[i + 1] != " "):
            prev += 1

    matches = []
    left, right = 0, len(text)
    while left <= right:
        try:
            ind = text.index(subs, left, right)
            matches.append(indices[ind])
            left = ind + 1
        except:
            break
    return matches
```

##### Test

```py
text = "we dont     need no education we dont need no thought control no we dont"
subs = "we dont"
print(doIt(text, subs))
```

Output

```py
[0, 5, 12]
```